# Tool to replicate a computer with Windows/Linux dual boot

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, hardware, hard-disk

I have 6 identical laptops with nothing installed on them. I want to install OS, application software and drivers into all of them. How can I achieve that with minimum efforts and time.

I have tried installing *Symantec Ghost Standard Tools 3.1*. However I have no clue how to proceed further. I have no knowledge of networking and neither I have infrastructure to preform a network install.

[image: The image shows the application that were installed through Symantec Ghost Standard Tools 3.1]

*The image shows the application that were installed through Symantec Ghost Standard Tools 3.1*

I also wish to learn how can I replicate a laptop with linux and windows installed in dual boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are truly identical, i.e. same hardware, etc., then possibly the easiest process is to install **but do not register**, Windows on a single machine - you can even install additional software, install your linux image & grub *making a note of all of the patition details* to get dual boot working.

Then boot that machine from a cloning tool such as [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org/) or [PartImage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) and create an image of that machines whole hard drive including all partitions on something like a USB hard drive tutorial here. On the other machines you will repeat the process but installing from the image. *You may also need to use parted magic to recreate the partitions noted above*.  Once installation is complete you can boot into Windows and only then register the Windows installation - if you register Windows on the original machine the image will not work on other hardware.

[Linux Live UDB Creator](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) can help to create your bootable USB device including CloneZilla but I would recommend creating one based on [CloneZilla-SysRescCD](http://clonezilla-sysresccd.hellug.gr/) which will give you access to all of the tools that you might need or [System Rescue CD](https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) alone if you are going to use PartImage.

You may well need to enter the BIOS on each of the machines to enable USB booting and may have to change a security setting to allow non-Microsoft signed software to boot.

Microsoft Deployment Toolkit, [MDT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn475741.aspx), also allows you to create custom Windows installations and deploy them but unless you have a lot of machines to install I would recommend just using it to install a customised Windows and then add the Linux and Grub installation manually seperately. If you prepartition your hard drives than install Windows using a MDT generated image and follow on with installing Linux from a boot USB and setting up the Dual boot it is quite quick.

Note that, while it is tempting to use a DVD rather than a USB stick or USB hard drive, DVDs are much slower for reading information than USB 3 devices espeically memory based devices such as USB sticks or some USB drives.

One word of warning - If you are trying to install Windows 7 from USB 2/3 you will need to patch the Windows 7 install image using the MS toolkit both for the initial installer boot environment and for the image(s) that you are planning on installing. I know from bitter experience that later USB hardware is not supported *to the level of not being able to use rather than not being able to take advantage of the full speed* by the Win7 SP1 images.

Comment: worked perfectly Steve. I tried it through VirtualBox and it produced the exactly what I wanted. Thanks for recommending! However, I was not able to create a virtual portable HDD so that I can save the test image created by CloneZilla. I have to arrange a physical portable HDD to perform the test. Any solution for that. Also, url for tutorial was skipped in the above answer!